# How to call Android ByteBuffer.putFloat() in JNI

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, bytebuffer

In Android/Java, we use `ByteBuffer` and can call `putFloat()`. I am trying to pass a `ByteBuffer` to a JNI cpp class and I can't figure out how to correctly store the `float` values. It's been a while since I have used C++...

Android Example of storing a `float` in `ByteBuffer`:

```
val bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(...)
bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
bb.putFloat(1.45f)
```

Calling the JNI method in Java/Kotlin:

```
val bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(imageSize * imageSize * 3 * 4)
bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())

//JNI Method
updateByteBufferWithFloatValues(bb)
```

JNI Method

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_sample_test_SampleFragment_updateByteBufferWithFloatValues(
    JNIEnv* env,
    jobject /* this */,
    jobject dstBB) {

jbyte* dstBuffer = (jbyte*)(*env).GetDirectBufferAddress(dstBB);

int bufferPos = 0;

//Other logic

dstBuffer[bufferPos] = 1.45f;
bufferPos++;

//Other logic

}
```

Float values need to range `-1.0` to `1.0`. I think the issue is when I am declaring `dstBuffer` and it needs to be created as something else that can store floats.

Comment: Can't you just do `jfloat* dstBuffer = (jfloat*)(*env).GetDirectBufferAddress(dstBB);` ?

Comment: Looks good to me! You probably want to change `dstBuffer` from a `jbyte*` to a `jfloat*`.

Comment: That worked. I thought I tried that earlier and I was only seeing 0s. Maybe I had broken logic somewhere else. Thanks!